# How Do I Combine These Two JQuery Statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I combine these two JQuery statements? This is for a bootstrap carousel manipulated with JQuery.

```
$('.carousel').carousel(randomNumber);
```

and

```
$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 6500 })
```

The first statement sets a random slide, and the second sets the interval. I know this should be relatively easy but I've had some trouble figuring it out and I can't find any other examples.

Comment: randomNumber I think it is another option value, then something like this should work: $('.carousel').carousel({ OPTIONNAME: randomNumber, interval: 6500 })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods are totally different.

This method is to set options for a carousel which can contain interval, pause, and wrap.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 6500, pause: "hover", wrap: true });
```

However, this method is to set a current slide.

```
$('.carousel').carousel(number);
```

It's impossible to call the methods at the same time, but you can use chaining like below:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 6500}).carousel(randomNumber);
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6XTPg/)

You will see the carousel moving to the 3rd slide as soon as it loads.